# Retrieve Android Device Manufactured date Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-hardware

I need to find the Android Device manufactured Date through my code I have gone through the [android.os.Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) API But Didn't find such a method

is possible to get Android Device Manufactured Date or Not?

Comment: Do OEMs provide such an information in any form (except what's put in stickers at the back of certain phones)?

Comment: 5 years later. do we a solution for this now?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Log.i("ManuFacturer :", Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("Board : ", Build.BOARD);
Log.i("Diaply : ", Build.DISPLAY);
```

Here is the documentations of that: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Comment: I need Manufactured Date not the name of Manufacturer

Comment: The `Build.TIME` field is likely what you're after though it's not documented as to what that field actually describes. If you look at the source code for the `Build` object you'll see the following: public static final long TIME = getLong("ro.build.date.utc") * 1000;

Comment: @Karl: `Build.TIME` is the time the binary was built. It changes every time a new binary is downloaded or the device gets a system upgrade.

Comment: Upvote for you considering the Android docs don't even explain that :p Cheers for the info.

Comment: @Sameer, by getting system updates: Settings > About > System updates

Answer (score 2):

You can get the date the OS was installed.

```
Date osInstalledDate = new Date(Build.TIME);
Log.i("MW",  "time from Build.TIME = " + osInstalledDate .toString());
```

Unfortunately if they re-install the OS this won't work.

Comment: When testing on my android device I saw this in the logcat "mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Thu Oct 25 08:43:05 KST 2012". This looks like a manufacture date or the compile date? I havn't figured out how to extract this in the android app yet.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get to the Device is with the `TelephonyManager`.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Log.d("X", tm.getDeviceId() + ", " + tm.getDeviceSoftwareVersion());
```

There you get the IMEI, Software Version and some information about the current Cell and SIM card. But device depenedant date: no, not yet in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Presently there is no API in Android to get Android Device Manufactured Date. From `Build.TIME` you can get OS installation or up-gradation date.

Answer (score -1):

On samsung oneui devices we can dial `*#12580*369#` and  see the manufactured date. RF Cal shows the manufactured date there.

But I have no idea to retrieve it programatically.

[image]