# Is there a way to find age of an Android device

Tags: android, systemtime

I want to find out how long the device has been used. I dont want the uptime i want the actual time elapsed from the device first boot

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242307/android-device-age

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
Log.i("ManuFacturer :", Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("Board : ", Build.BOARD);
Log.i("Diaply : ", Build.DISPLAY);
Log.i("Time : ", Build.TIME);
```

Unfortunately the `Build.TIME` will be reset when new ROM is installed.

reference: [Retrieve Android Device Manufactured date Programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956723/retrieve-android-device-manufactured-date-programatically)